# Assign value to exteral variable within jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Here is my code:

```
var resultSet;

db.transaction(function (tx){
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?', [name], function (tx, results) {
        resultSet = results;
    });
});

console.log(resultSet);
```

What is logged is "undefined".

What I am hoping to get is the SQLResultSet object "results" assigned to "resultSet".

I am sure I am misunderstanding scoping in JavaScript. But this seems like it should work and I can't find a similar question asked.

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Your parenthesis aren't balanced; `tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?', [name], function (tx, results) {` should probably be `tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?', [name], function (tx, results)) {`

Comment: @Nelson - Sorry...it's not... I simply edited the query to keep it simple. You can assume it's defined.

Comment: @stealthyninja - the parens are balanced - it's an annoymous call back function... the closing paren follows the closing "}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `transaction` or `executeSql` is an asychronous function, meaning anything involving its result MUST be included in the callback function.

Comment: Thanks. This and Frédéric Hamidi's comment on another answer to this question are making me see my mistake. I apparently don't fully understand the asynchronous nature of JS yet.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `console.log()` with `resultSet` before the query has a chance to return.

Move the call to `log()` into the query callback:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?', [name], function(tx, results) {
        console.log(results);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes - I am calling console.log to see if it gets set. My purpose is not to log it, but to assign "results" to "resultset".

Comment: You can assign `result` to `resultSet`, but then you cannot use `resultSet` outside of the callback because it will not be assigned yet. In general, asynchronous functions cannot modify external state that easily.

Comment: Frédéric Hamidi - I think I understand now. This, while seeming incredibly limiting, makes sense...

Comment: @user, only the syntax is limiting (that's why the C# designers recently have added `async` and `await` keywords to the language), asynchronous behavior is actually quite powerful. Maybe a future version of something like Coffescript, of maybe Javascript itself, will support syntactic sugar like this.

Comment: Thanks Frédéric for your help. I'll have to get creative then :)